# VBA - Item not found in this collection - Can't find why

Tags: vba, ms-access

In need of some assistance. I'm not a programmer nor fluent in VBA yet somehow ended up trying to automate an old Access file that my company manually runs every week. It takes over 2 hours to run manually, so Automation seemed worth it. Seems to have gotten most of it down but it fails on the last few commands now. Takes about an hour to run before the error occurs as well, so troubleshooting takes forever.

I don't really know what I'm doing if I'm gonna be honest. Been using examples from different answers that I've found to other similar questions to automate this so far and the first 5 steps run without issue. I've tried other answers to this error but they've not yet fixed it for me and as I'm pretty much just throwing stuff at a wall and seeing what sticks, I'm not really sure how to proceed.

Here's the code that gives the error:

```
strSQL = ""
strSQL = strSQL & "SELECT Alla_Aktiva.LEVID AS [FINFO LEVERANTÖRSNR], Alla_Aktiva.FINFONR AS [FINFO ARTIKELNUMMER], Alla_Aktiva.LEVARTNR AS [LEVERANTÖRS ARTIKELNUMMER], Alla_Aktiva.PTISWEDISH AS INGRESS, Alla_Aktiva.PTKSWEDISH AS PRODUKTTEXT, Alla_Aktiva.PTTSWEDISH AS [TEKNISK BESKRIVNING], Alla_Aktiva.PTPSWEDISH AS PUNKTLISTA "
strSQL = strSQL & "FROM FINFO_ORDERS_GRBES00 INNER JOIN Alla_Aktiva ON FINFO_ORDERS_GRBES00.SUPPLIERFROM_BELNRF = Alla_Aktiva.LEVID "
strSQL = strSQL & "WHERE (((FINFO_ORDERS_GRBES00.SUBSCRIBERID_BEABN)=39221"
strSQL = strSQL & "));"

db.QueryDefs.Delete "ExportData2"
Set queData = db.CreateQueryDef("ExportData2", strSQL)
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12Xml, "ExportData2", "G:\Finfo_Jobb\MCLankar\MC Stat\Utskick\Abo-" & 39221 & "" & Format$(Now(), "YYYYMMDDHHMMSS") & ".xlsx", True
```

db.QueryDefs.Delete "ExportData2" - this gets marked as the error with item not found in this collection as the error

So this should, in theory, generate a statistics report of how much data each Supplier (Leverantör in Swedish) has on their products and put it in an Excel file which is placed on our shared network disk (G:)

Since it takes over an hour to run each time I try something new, I'm getting a bit frustrated with it and only have 3 more days until I go on a 3 week vacation and getting this up and running before then would allow me to not work during that vacation, generating the report. :p

Any help would be greatly appreciated

(Why my company is using Access to generate statistics from a product database of several million products and a few hundred different datapoints per product is beyond me :p (It's the way it's always been done-mentality and no financial incentive to update to something more suitable, but yeah...))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the QueryDef is not required at this point (you are deleting it, BUT it does not actually exist). A simple check to see if it exists before deleting it is all you need.

Modifying your code as below should resolve the issue for you.

```
strSQL = ""
strSQL = strSQL & "SELECT Alla_Aktiva.LEVID AS [FINFO LEVERANTÖRSNR], Alla_Aktiva.FINFONR AS [FINFO ARTIKELNUMMER], Alla_Aktiva.LEVARTNR AS [LEVERANTÖRS ARTIKELNUMMER], Alla_Aktiva.PTISWEDISH AS INGRESS, Alla_Aktiva.PTKSWEDISH AS PRODUKTTEXT, Alla_Aktiva.PTTSWEDISH AS [TEKNISK BESKRIVNING], Alla_Aktiva.PTPSWEDISH AS PUNKTLISTA "
strSQL = strSQL & "FROM FINFO_ORDERS_GRBES00 INNER JOIN Alla_Aktiva ON FINFO_ORDERS_GRBES00.SUPPLIERFROM_BELNRF = Alla_Aktiva.LEVID "
strSQL = strSQL & "WHERE (((FINFO_ORDERS_GRBES00.SUBSCRIBERID_BEABN)=39221"
strSQL = strSQL & "));"

' Modified Code below
    Dim qdf As DAO.QueryDef

    For Each qdf In CurrentDb.QueryDefs
      If qdf.Name = "ExportData2" Then
        CurrentDb.QueryDefs.Delete "ExportData2"
         Exit For
      End If
    Next
'End modified code

Set queData = db.CreateQueryDef("ExportData2", strSQL)
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12Xml, "ExportData2", "G:\Finfo_Jobb\MCLankar\MC Stat\Utskick\Abo-" & 39221 & "" & Format$(Now(), "YYYYMMDDHHMMSS") & ".xlsx", True
```

Comment: Thanks! Trying it out right now. Reporting back in a few hours... :p